# Which tasks are needed to build my reactTS application to bamboo and deploy it to nexus?

Tags: npm, nexus, bamboo, react-tsx

I have a react application that works fine locally both build and start. I am trying to build the application from my bitbucket repo into bamboo and further deploy it to nexus through a task script. I am new to bamboo and I have problem finding any clear information on which tasks I need. 
Appreciate all the help and recommendations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of [Atlassian's Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/understanding-the-bamboo-ci-server-289277285.html) on setting up a CI/CD server as a good primer.  Specifically the guides under the [Continuous Integration](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-bamboo-289276852.html) section.

You are going to need to do the following:

**Make sure you setup node and any other dependencies on the Bamboo server first**

1. Setup a Bamboo project that is a "repository" of your different build plans.
2. Setup a Bamboo plan that contains the specific "jobs" that are required to build (in this case get the source code and build it.
3. Setup a task to checkout source code from Bitbucket.
4. Setup a task to build the source code.

Once you have that setup you can then dive into the Continuous Deployment sections of the guides to learn about how to handle generic deployments using Bamboo.  You can adapt these steps for your Nexus specific deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was asking for specific task which is deploying to nexus from Bamboo for a ReactTS application

Comment: The linked to Atlassian Documentation has plenty of information about how to script a deployment task.  You are going to need a build artifact first though which is what the bulk of my posted answer will provide.